# How to animate multiple elements, when using the same classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, optimization

I'm am trying to make multiple boxes, which can expand onclick and close again when clicking on the X. Well first off, the close jquery doesn't work, but that isn't the main thing I'am looking fore, how can I optimize the code, so doesn't become 400-600 hundred lines of the same, just for each box/element.

When click on one box/element, it should expand and so should the content inside - in the order as they come. Then it can be closed again an you would be able to click on another element with the same result - using pretty much the same code. 
How can I make the site know, which element has bin click on.

Thanks in advance :)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".calendarBox" ).click(function() {
    $(".calendarBox").addClass("calendarBoxOpen").delay(2000);
    $(".dateTitle").addClass("dateTitleOpen");
    $(".dateMonthBox").addClass("dateMonthBoxOpen");
    $(".closeMonth").addClass("showMonth");
    $(".dateDayBox").addClass("dateDayBoxOpen");
    $(".closeDay").addClass("showDay");
    $(".dateCloseBtnBox").addClass("dateOpenBtnBox");
    $(".closeHr").addClass("showHr");
    $(".dayActivitiesInfo").addClass("dayActivitiesInfoOpned");
    $(".dayInfoTxt_1May").addClass("dayInfoTxt_1MayOpen");
    $(".dayInfoBtnBox_1Maj").addClass("dayInfoBtnBox_1MajOpen");
  }); 
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".dateCloseBtn" ).click(function() {         
   $(".dayInfoBtnBox_1Maj").removeClass("dayInfoBtnBox_1MajOpen");
    $(".dayInfoTxt_1May").removeClass("dayInfoTxt_1MayOpen");
    $(".dayActivitiesInfo").removeClass("dayActivitiesInfoOpned");
    $(".closeHr").removeClass("showHr"); 
    $(".dateCloseBtnBox").removeClass("dateOpenBtnBox");
    $(".closeDay").removeClass("showDay");
    $(".dateDayBox").removeClass("dateDayBoxOpen");
    $(".closeMonth").removeClass("showMonth");
    $(".dateMonthBox").removeClass("dateMonthBoxOpen");
    $(".dateTitle").removeClass("dateTitleOpen");
    $(".calendarBox").removeClass("calendarBoxOpen");
  });
});
```

```css
.calendarBox { /*This is when closed*/
  width:14.28571428571428%;
  border:0.5px solid #000;
  height:100%;
  transition-duration:1s;
}

.calendarBox:hover {
  background-color:#8abcc2;
}

.calendarBoxOpen { /*This is when opened*/
  width:57.14285714285712%;
} 

.calendarDate {
  
}

.calendarHeader {
  display:flex;
}

.dateTitle { /*This is when closed*/
  margin-left:15px;
  display:none;
  transition:ease-in-out;
  transition-duration:1s;
}

.dateTitleOpen { /*This is when opened*/
  display:block; 
  
}

.dateDayMonthBox {
  width:100%;
}

.dateMonthBox { /*This is when closed*/
  display:inline-flex; 
  float:right;
}

.dateMonthBoxOpen { /*This is when Opened*/
  margin-left:25px;
}

.closeMonth { /*This is when closed*/
  display:none;
}

.showMonth { /*This is when opened*/
  display:block;
}

.dateDayBox { /*This is when closed*/
  display:inline-flex;
  float:left;/*This is when open*/
}

.dateDayBoxOpen { /*This is when opened*/
  float:right;
}

.closeDay { /*This is when closed*/
  display:none;
}

.showDay { /*This is when opened*/
  display:block; 
}

.dateCloseBtnBox { /*This is when date is closed*/
   -webkit-margin-before: 1.33em;
   -webkit-margin-after: 1.33em;
   -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
   -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin-left:25px;
   margin-right:5px;
   display:none;
}

.dateOpenBtnBox { /*This is visible, when date open*/
   display:block;
}

.dateCloseBtn {

}

.closeHr { /*This is when closed*/
  display:none;
}

.showHr { /*This is when opened*/
  display:block;
}

/*====Content of the calendar day=====*/

.dateDayInformationBox {
  
}

.dateDayInformation {
  width:100%;
  display:inline-flex;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}

.dayActivitiesInfo { /*This is when closed*/
  height:18px;
  width:100%; 
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  list-style-type:none;
  border-left:2.5px solid purple;
}

.dayActivitiesInfoOpned { /*This is when opened*/
  height:100%; 
  width:50%;  
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  list-style-type:none;
  border-left:2.5px solid purple;
}

/*====The txt======*/

.dayInfoTitel_1May {
  
}

.dayInfoTxt_1May { /*This is when closed*/
  display:none;
}

.dayInfoTxt_1MayOpen { /*This is when opened*/
  display:block;
}

.dayInfoBtnBox_1Maj { /*This is when closed*/
   display:none;
}

.dayInfoBtnBox_1MajOpen { /*This is when opened*/
   text-align: center;
   margin: auto;
   display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<div class="calendarBox">
  <div class="calendarDate">
    <div class="calendarHeader">
      <h3 class="dateTitle">Information</h3>
      <div class="dateDayMonthBox">        
          <div class="dateMonthBox"><h4 class="">1</h4><h4 class="closeMonth">.Maj</h4></div>           <div class="dateDayBox"><h4 class="">M</h4><h4 class="closeDay">andag</h4></div>
      </div>      
      <div class="dateCloseBtnBox">
        <div class="dateCloseBtn">close</div>
      </div><!--The clouse btn-->      
    </div>
    <hr class="closeHr">
    <div class="dateDayInformationBox">
      <div class="dateDayInformation">
        <ul class="dayActivitiesInfo">
          <li class="dayInfoTitel_1May">Børnekor - kl.14:40</li>
          <li class="dayInfoTxt_1May">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis aliquam nunc sit amet ante lacinia, vitae dictum erat egestas. Duis rutrum vitae orci vitae euismod.</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="dayInfoBtnBox_1Maj">
          <h5>Tilmeldte 23 <span>Icon</span></h5>
          <div>
            <button>Del</button>
            <button>Tilmeld</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dateDayInformation">
        <ul class="dayActivitiesInfo">
          <li class="dayInfoTitel_1May">Bord og Vin - kl.18:30</li>
          <li class="dayInfoTxt_1May">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis aliquam nunc sit amet ante lacinia, vitae dictum erat egestas. Duis rutrum vitae orci vitae euismod.</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="dayInfoBtnBox_1Maj">
          <h5>Tilmeldte 23 <span>Icon</span></h5>
          <div>
            <button>Del</button>
            <button>Tilmeld</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!---------><div class="close">
close
</div>


<div class="calendarBox" onclick="animateDayOpen_1Maj">
  <div class="calendarDate">
    <div class="calendarHeader">
      <h3 class="dateTitle">Information</h3>
      <div class="dateDayMonthBox">        
          <div class="dateMonthBox"><h4 class="">2</h4><h4 class="closeMonth">.Maj</h4></div>           <div class="dateDayBox"><h4 class="">M</h4><h4 class="closeDay">andag</h4></div>
      </div>      
      <div class="dateCloseBtnBox" onclick="animateDayClose_1Maj">
        <div class="dateCloseBtn">X</div>
      </div><!--The clouse btn-->      
    </div>
    <hr class="closeHr">
    <div class="dateDayInformationBox">
      <div class="dateDayInformation">
        <ul class="dayActivitiesInfo">
          <li class="dayInfoTitel_1May">Børnekor - kl.14:40</li>
          <li class="dayInfoTxt_1May">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis aliquam nunc sit amet ante lacinia, vitae dictum erat egestas. Duis rutrum vitae orci vitae euismod.</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="dayInfoBtnBox_1Maj">
          <h5>Tilmeldte 23 <span>Icon</span></h5>
          <div>
            <button>Del</button>
            <button>Tilmeld</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dateDayInformation">
        <ul class="dayActivitiesInfo">
          <li class="dayInfoTitel_1May">Bord og Vin - kl.18:30</li>
          <li class="dayInfoTxt_1May">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis aliquam nunc sit amet ante lacinia, vitae dictum erat egestas. Duis rutrum vitae orci vitae euismod.</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="dayInfoBtnBox_1Maj">
          <h5>Tilmeldte 23 <span>Icon</span></h5>
          <div>
            <button>Del</button>
            <button>Tilmeld</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use $(this) to refer to the clicked element

Answer (score 0):

So, you have multiple boxes that you want to expand/shrink on click. You can give all that boxes one class - `boxExpandable` for expample, with initial width. Then user clicks on `boxExpandable` - you should toggle `.expanded` class with higher width.
If you want some content to be shown only when box is expanded - wrap it in `.showWhenExpanded` class, like shown below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.expandableBox').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 40%;
  border: solid 5px goldenrod;
  transition: background-color .4s, width .4s;
}

.box:hover {
  background-color: #32cd32;
}

.box.expanded {
  width: 80%;
}

.showWhenExpanded {
  display: none;
}

.box.expanded .showWhenExpanded {
  display: inline-block;    
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script> 

<div class="content">
  <div class="box expandableBox">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <span class="showWhenExpanded">Duis aliquam nunc sit amet ante lacinia, vitae dictum erat egestas. Duis rutrum vitae orci vitae euismod.</span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box expandableBox">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <span class="showWhenExpanded">Duis aliquam nunc sit amet ante lacinia, vitae dictum erat egestas. Duis rutrum vitae orci vitae euismod.</span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box expandableBox">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <span class="showWhenExpanded">Duis aliquam nunc sit amet ante lacinia, vitae dictum erat egestas. Duis rutrum vitae orci vitae euismod.</span></p>
  </div> 
</div>
```

See [this codepen](https://codepen.io/fen1x/pen/ZKmrvw)

Comment: Year that was the idea, I have seen one the solution that you suggest, but the problem is the content inside which also has to expand or become visible (get display:block;) and it would a lot of repetitions, when there is going to be many boxes. Like a calendar, when closed you only see the headline, but when click on, it expand and shows more text and so on.

Comment: I modified my snippet to show how you can hide content when box is not expanded.

Comment: I see how this may help and it would work for some of the elements, those who only have to be turn display block or none, but take the class [ .dayActivitiesInfo ] has a width of 100% on closed - when opened goes to [ .dayActivitiesInfoOpned ] change the width to 50%.